# SQL query to bring back max of multiple rows

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks something likes this:

```
A    B    C
1    2    2
3    4    6
1    2    3
3    4    5
3    4    4
1    2    1
```

What I need to do is given an array of two dimensional tuples representing **A** and **B**, I need to bring back the row for each that has the maximum **C**.

For example if my array was `[(1,2)]` then my resulting table should be this as for `A=1` and `B=2` then my maximum **C** is 3

```
A    B    C
1    2    3
```

If my array was `[(1,2), (3,4)]` then my resulting table should be this as for `A=1` and `B=2` then my maximum **C** is 3 and for `A=3` and `B=4` my maximum **C** is 6

```
A    B    C
1    2    3
3    4    6
```

I feel this can probably done by using an SQl subquery. Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT A, B, C 
  FROM my_table
 WHERE my_array IN (SELECT A, B, C, MAX(C) 
                      FROM my_table 
                     WHERE **not sure what goes here**)
```

Is there a benefit to doing this in a single SQL query rather than doing an SQL query for each element of my array?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: No one in particular actually. I would also be interested if there were different ways depending on which DBMS is being used

Comment: from my experience, the subquery method usually is more inefficient because of the size of the dataset you are looking at in the subquery, but I've also had cases where the subquery was more efficient because the size of the outer query was not significant. it all turns out that the efficiency of your query will depend on the use of indexes and size of the returned data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `MAX`:

```
SELECT A, B, MAX(C) AS C
FROM tab
GROUP BY A, B
ORDER BY A, B;
```

**EDIT:**

If SQL Server you could use table variable:

```
DECLARE @my_array AS TABLE(A  INT, B INT);
INSERT INTO @my_array(A, B) VALUES (1,2);


SELECT t.A, t.B, MAX(t.C) AS C
FROM tab t
JOIN @my_array ma
  ON t.A = ma.A AND t.B = ma.B
GROUP BY t.A, t.B
ORDER BY t.A, t.B;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/ZAKI72782)**

Comment: This doesn't have my_array has input anywhere

Comment: you need to insert your array in the table @my_array.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A, B, MAX(C) AS C FROM #temp where a=1 and b=2 GROUP BY A, B
```

Comment: This is only for a=1,b=2. Can it work easily if we had an array of possible values for them?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

A co-related subquery will do that:

```
select t1.*
from my_table t1
where (t1.a, t1.b) = in ( values (1,2), (3,4) )
  and t1.c = (select max(c) 
              from my_table t2
              where t1.a = t2.a
                and t1.b = t2.b)
order by t1.a, t1.b;
```

You can avoid the co-related subquery if you want to. Sometimes they tend to be slower then equivalent solutions:

```
select t1.*
from my_table t1
where (t1.a, t1.b, t1.c) in (select t2.a, t2.b, max(t2.c) 
                             from my_table t2
                             where (t2.a, t2.b) in (values (1,2), (3,4))
                             group by t2.a, t2.b)
order by t1.a, t1.b;
```

The part with `values (1,2), (3,4)` is you "array input".

The above is standard ANSI SQL.

Online example: http://rextester.com/QPY97515